# Transparency on black/white raster after clipping in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity, clip

I'm new to QGIS.  It seems as if this problem doesn't show up with ArcGIS.

I clipped a black/white raster. Unfortunately the surrounding background after clipping is also black. When I set the transparency to 0, black areas within my raster get white. I'ld like to avoid that. So here's what's happening in pictures:

[image: clipped black/white raster]

[image: clipped black/white raster with transparency]

So one workaround could be to just overlay the vector layer and raster, then it's perfect:

[image]

But I need this layer as only one raster or vector and not only as an overlay in QGIS.

So how can I save that?

Converting the raster into a vector or vector into a raster for some reason doesn't work as I would expect it to do.

Comment: looks like this may help you out:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40765/how-to-surround-a-clipped-raster-with-transparency-gdalwarp?rq=1

Comment: In the original data, are the areas outside Germany 0 or NULL?