# Remove unwanted black area around clipped raster in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, qgis-2.18

Following on from [Remove white background in Raster in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133852/remove-white-background-in-raster-in-qgis/133862?noredirect=1#comment390056_133862)

When I choose the unwanted value - in my case I want to remove black area around the clipped raster - I write `0` as the unwanted value, but I also lose a lot of important detail in the clipped raster. So there is a lot of differences between the original raster to the clipped raster

[image]

How can I choose to remove only the black area around the clipped raster?

Comment: Have you tried `gdalwarp -q -cutline clip.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha ` https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40765/how-to-surround-a-clipped-raster-with-transparency-gdalwarp?rq=1 ?

Comment: i saw this answer-don't understand what to do??

Comment: if using 0 as NULL value also affects other parts of your raster, you maybe want to assign a more unique value in the clip dialog. try -9999 and use that as your additional NULL value for transparency

Comment: i write 9999 in the unwanted value-nothing happend.

Comment: use the info cursor and click on the black area. you should see the info window with the cell value of one of the black raster cells. is it 9999? if so, if you right click on your raster layer > properties > transparency, did you use THAT value in 'additional NULL value'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally, I found this solution: I put on top the layer with the desirable area i want to crop. then in the clipper function, i mark those two options:

[image]

The result will be the exact area without black areas

[image]